# Access Laravel Queued Job's payload data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I access the payload from within the Laravel job class?

I have tried:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\PDF;

class ProcessConversion implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $pdf;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(PDF $pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        $payload = $this->payload(); //undefined method
        $payload = $this->payload; //undefined property
        $payload = json_decode($this->getRawBody(), true); //undefined method

        ....
```

I got these from the Job class. But [payload()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php#L178) and [getRawBody()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/RedisJob.php#L71) both return `Call to undefined method`.

Other methods [from that class do work](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/RedisJob.php#L94) - for example, `$this->release(1)`, so I'm not sure if `$this` does refer to the actual job class.

I am using the Redis queue driver, using Laravel 5.4.

Comment: What are you expecting to get from the `payload()` method? Normally you'd pass in the data the job requires via the constructor, like you have done with the `PDF` class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're able to call the `$this->release()` method is because that's a method which is added into your `ProcessConversion` class via the trait `InteractsWithQueue` (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.php#L57)

You may be able to have your class extend the abstract `Job` class (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php) which *might* give you access to those methods you're hoping for, however, i'm unable to find any documentation on this.

Comment: The class in question doesn't implement the interface of the `Job` class, so doing that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using `$payload = $this->job->payload()` instead?